# Running a scheduled task as a domain user - C:\Users\TEMP is created

Tags: installation, scheduled-tasks, domain

I am trying to run a scheduled task that runs as a domain admin user (let's call it DOMAIN\installer). Part of this scheduled task runs automated installers for our network. One such installer I have been working on gives me the following error during install through this scheduled task:

```
MSI (s) (00:24) [14:01:57:829]: 
The profile for the user is a temporary profile.
```

Upon further inspection, I have noticed that a "user profile" called C:\Users\TEMP is created when the task is run and then deletes itself immediately after (along with the HKEY_USERS keys for it). There is no folder for DOMAIN\installer. It seems like the DOMAIN\installer profile has been corrupted somehow, but I am not sure how that happened. In the past, the DOMAIN\installer user account would remain in the users list and registry indefinitely.

Basically, I am trying to figure out why this is happening and how I can fix it. I need to be able to install this program using the DOMAIN\installer account, but because it is showing up as TEMP the program will not install.

Any help would be great.